# CSS Loginform failed

Tags: css, forms, authentication

Look at my login-form ([enter link description here](http://tekkkz.zapto.org:8080/).
I don't know why, but the Text-Field is not as large as the login-field -10px left and right (margin).
What did I wrong?
I hope you can help me, Thanks!

Codes:
Markup:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="widget">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form class="login_form">
            <p>
                <label for="auth_id">Auth-Id:</label>
                <input id="auth_id" type="text" name="auth_id">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="submit">
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
.sidebar .widget {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #0b145f;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #f8f8fe;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), 0px 3px 0px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.8), 0px 3px 0px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.sidebar .widget h1 {
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    margin: 13px 10px 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #0b145f;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar .widget p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sidebar .widget .login_form label {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    display: block;
}
.sidebar .widget .login_form input {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add an isolated example of your markup and your css to your question?

Comment: I addeded code now, please check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the input its own width, right now it is inheriting the width of the form and when you added the `padding` and `margin` it pushes it outside the container.

```
.sidebar .widget .login_form input {
    margin: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 70%;
}
```